# Decrypt PHP ChaChaPoly encrypted data in Swift

Tags: php, swift, encryption, apple-cryptokit, cryptokit

I am trying to decrypt data with Swift CryptoKit that I have encrypted with php using `openssl_encrypt()` `chacha20-poly1305`. Encrypting works, but when decrypting I get the error: `incorrectParameterSize` (Swift: error 1, line 10).

**PHP encryption using openssl_encrypt:**

```
<?php
$plaintext = "Hello World";
$key = base64_decode("O7IaTssF6RKgc84b8daAHojiveFY4vyQ4zKRZv3APKc=");
$nonce = base64_decode("MmTNTi+MmTNTi+fB");
$encrypted = 
openssl_encrypt(
    $plaintext,
    'chacha20-poly1305',
    $key,
    0,
    $nonce
);

echo $encrypted;
```

**Swift decryption using CryptoKit**

```
import CryptoKit
import Foundation
let encoded_data = "OG54KzRFKytSSmQ5d0M4PQ=="
let encoded_nonce = "MmTNTi+MmTNTi+fB"
let encoded_key = "O7IaTssF6RKgc84b8daAHojiveFY4vyQ4zKRZv3APKc="
let data = Data(base64Encoded: encoded_data)!
let nonce = Data(base64Encoded: encoded_nonce)!
let key = SymmetricKey(data: Data(base64Encoded: encoded_key)!)
do{
    let box = try ChaChaPoly.SealedBox(combined: data.base64EncodedData())
    do{
        let decryptedData = try ChaChaPoly.open(box,using: key)
        let decryptedString = String(decoding: decryptedData, as: UTF8.self)
        print("Decrypted string: \(decryptedString)")
    }catch{
        print("error 2: \(error)")
    }
}catch{
    print("error 1: \(error)")
}
```

I also tried using `sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt()` to encrypt, which resulted in the error "authenticationFailure" (Swift: error 2, line 12).

**PHP encryption using sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt:**

```
<?php

$plaintext = "Hello World";
$key = base64_decode("O7IaTssF6RKgc84b8daAHojiveFY4vyQ4zKRZv3APKc=");
$nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_NPUBBYTES);
$encrypted = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt($plaintext,"",$nonce, $key);

echo "Data:" . base64_encode($encrypted) . "\n";
echo "Nonce:" . base64_encode($nonce);
```

Comment: You do not use the key in the 1st PHP code, but pass a `NULL` instead. Also, `ChaCha20-Poly1305` applies a 96 bit (12 bytes), which is why the PHP code gives an appropriate warning (probably the Base64 decoding is missing). Furthermore, the PHP code Base64 encodes the ciphertext twice (implicitly because the 4th parameter passed to `openssl_encrypt()` is `0`, and once explicitly).

Comment: Thanks, my bad, should actually look like this. (edited it, hopefully correct.)
But there is still the same error.

Comment: Future readers might find it easier to reconcile post and comments if you don't change the original post, but append your changes to the end of the original post. Anyway, there seems to be a problem with the tag generation for `chacha20-poly1305`, see this issue ([#76935](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76935)). There, another library is given, which can be used alternatively, including a usage example.

Comment: You mean the error is in the PHP file? Because the encryption and decryption using PHP works fine. I just get an error when decrypting using swift.

Comment: Yes, see my answer for more details and a PHP/Sodium based solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a real-world scenario, you would need to validate the data, nonce, and key before attempting to decrypt the data to ensure that they have not been modified or corrupted.

```
import CryptoKit
import Foundation

let encodedData = "OG54KzRFKytSSmQ5d0M4PQ=="
let encodedNonce = "MmTNTi+MmTNTi+fB"
let encodedKey = "O7IaTssF6RKgc84b8daAHojiveFY4vyQ4zKRZv3APKc="

guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: encodedData),
      let nonce = Data(base64Encoded: encodedNonce),
      let key = SymmetricKey(data: Data(base64Encoded: encodedKey)) else {
    print("Invalid data, nonce, or key")
    return
}

do {
    let box = try ChaChaPoly.SealedBox(combined: data)
    let decryptedData = try ChaChaPoly.open(box, using: key)
    let decryptedString = String(decoding: decryptedData, as: UTF8.self)
    print("Decrypted string: \(decryptedString)")
} catch {
    print("Decryption failed: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[*ChaCha20-Poly1305*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChaCha20-Poly1305) is [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), i.e. during encryption a tag is generated in addition to the ciphertext, which is required for authentication during decryption.
The PHP/OpenSSL code does not generate this tag due to a bug, which is therefore missing when decrypting with the Swift code, so decryption fails (PHP/OpenSSL internally decryption works). More details about the bug are described in [#76935](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76935).

---

PHP/Sodium, on the other hand, works:

```php
$plaintext = 'secret message';
$key = base64_decode('XohImNooBHFR0OVvjcYpJ3NgPQ1qq73WKhHvch0VQtg=');
$nonce = base64_decode('F6u88lkmmz8Rrjvf'); // for testing only, otherwise: random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES);
$nonceCtTag = $nonce . sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_encrypt($plaintext, '', $nonce, $key);
print(base64_encode($nonceCtTag) . PHP_EOL); // F6u88lkmmz8RrjvfJ22r4vrKmWuY8a2DNpjUKZVUi9Wp9QjZVgheBihn
```

The test data is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65969221/9014097), i.e. was generated with CryptoKit's *ChaCha20-Poly1305*, so decryption with your Swift code should give the original plaintext (the key corresponds to the SHA256 hash of `password`).

Note that `sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_encrypt()` returns as result the concatenation of ciphertext and tag, so that `$nonceCtTag` corresponds to the [`combined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/chachapoly/sealedbox/combined) representation (*nonce|ciphertext|tag*) to be passed in `SealedBox(combined: ...)`.

---

The code above uses [`sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-aead-chacha20poly1305-ietf-encrypt.php) with a 12 bytes nonce instead of `sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt()` with an 8 bytes nonce (see [here](https://doc.libsodium.org/secret-key_cryptography/aead#supported-constructions) for more details regarding the different variants).